# Built-in iterables: property length and accessor implications

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, accessor, iterable

Are all of javascript buit-in iterables that have the property `.length` able to access to their iterated elements via `[<numeric index>]` an vice versa?

```
Array -> has `.length` & has `[]` accessor
String -> has `.length` & has `[]` accessor
TypedArray -> has `.length` & has `[]` accessor
Set -> does not have `.length` & does not have `[]` accessor
Map -> does not have `.length` & does not have `[]` accessor
NodeList -> has `.length` & has `[]` accessor
HTMLCollection -> has `.length` & has `[]` accessor
```

I do not know if there are other built-in iterables which break this rule.

Comment: `NodeList` and `HTMLCollection` are no JavaScript builtins, they're DOM objects.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

I'd state this the other way round:

- All indexable collections do have a `.length` property
- All indexable collections are iterable (i.e. have a `[Symbol.iterator]` method)<sup>1</sup>

There is no official design statement in the spec that guarantees this (especially as a guideline for future collections), but we can simply tabularise all standard builtins this way just like you did in your question.

<sub>1: Notice that `String` already provides an exception to the expected rule that the iterated values would correspond to the indexed elements - it [iterates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator) code points instead of characters</sub>

Comment: Thanks @Bergi! It has been really useful.

Answer (score 0):

**Not all itterables in JavaScript have the property length**

Arrays (or sequences) have the property [**`.length`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length?v=example) to count the number of entries. Maps and Sets instead use the [**`.size`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/size) method.

Basically `.length` is used for sequences (data structures that are indexable), and `.size` is for collections that are usually unordered (e.g. Maps or Sets)

iterables (such as arrays) do not need to have a `.next()` method, and few of them do; instead, they have a special method Symbol.iterator that will return an iterator (that is, an object with the .next() method). 
(edit credit to @[frxstrem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/423170/frxstrem))

See the MDN documentation on [Iteration Protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)

Comment: Your third paragraph about the iteration protocol is incorrect: iterables (such as arrays) do not need to have a `.next` method, and few of them do; instead, they have a special method [`[Symbol.iterator]()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) that will 
*return* an iterator (that is, an object with the `.next()` method).

Comment: The first paragraph also is wrong. Map and Set has the property `size`, not the method `size()`. And that does not answer my question, sorry and thanks!

Comment: Thanks @xgbuils for spotting that (I was in Java mode lol), it's been updated now :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's an array, use `length`, if it's a collection, use `size`

Comment: Ha ha, succinctly put! And you can use the bracket notation for indexable structures too